# Placing entry stamps on the passport page before the page with a visa issued earlier

Tags: visas, passports, passport-stamps

I'm soon going to Russia and Kazakhstan, and for Russia, I Need a Transit visa.

My first passport page for stamps is 7, where I have two US entry stamps. Therefore, the Russian visa will be placed on page 8, and the entry/exit stamps, from what I've seen, are placed on the visa.

I don't want the Kazakh entry and exit stamps to be placed on a random page in the middle, so I'm going to ask them to stamp a specific page.

Is it OK if they stamp page 7, or should I ask them to stamp page 9? If they stamp on page 7 the page doesn't get wasted but the chronological order would not be right. Is that an issue?

Comment: As far as I know, there's definitely no order for visas or stamps in a passport, they just put it wherever they find space. Some officers just find the first available page, others just stamp anywhere they want. You may try to ask to stamp a specific page, but I fail to see a reason for this?

Comment: On a recent trip to Mexico, the officer at the border went through until they found a US stamp, and the Mexican entry stamp as close to that as possible. No idea why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no order of any kind in passport stampings, all countries stamp wherever they feel like / whatever is the first page to pop open.

If you ask nicely, they'll potentially stamp on the page you want them to, but potentially they also get suspect why you would want that.

Answer (score 4):

The only person who might be concerned about stamps being in chronological order is the passport holder.  Some folks like things neat and orderly, the rest of us could care less.

Likewise with Immigration and Consular officials, some are neat and orderly and will stamp your passport on the first available slot or completely empty page (depending on stamp or visa size), others will flip the passport open to whatever page they want and stamp away.  I have had countries put my visa on one page, the entry stamp on another and the exit stamp on a third page (though this is the extreme, as entry & exit stamps are usually put next to each other).

There are no government regulations that require you to use your pages in sequence or to use all four sections on each page.

The only downside to having stamps on random pages by themselves, is that some countries require 1 or 2 totally blank pages in your passport in order to issue a visa and if you have one stamp on each page trying to keep them separate, you may run out of blank pages to meet that requirement.  And then have to renew your passport.

Comment: "There are no government regulations that require you to [...] use all four sections on each page." Passport pages don't even necessarily _have_ sections. British passports don't, for example.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - Some countries have pages divided into quarters, some do not.  Those that do, do not require you to use all four .... Gosh do we need to write out encyclopedic answers citing all possible exclusions to statements we make?

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned here, there's no particular order to stamps/visas, you get them where you get them (but you can certainly try asking for a specific stamp placement). One more thing I wanted to add to the other answers: There's something I've seen in particular with ex-Soviet countries - for some reason many of the border officials like to put the entry/exit stamps at the **very back of the passport**. In fact, probably 90%+ of my Russian stamps were as far back in the passport as possible. (I don't need a visa to enter Russia, perhaps for visitors from visa-required countries the stamps are placed near the visa).