# Do blank passport pages have to be consecutive?

Tags: passport-stamps

I have several blank pages in between already stamped pages. They didn't stamp the first available page, they just opened my passport and stamped.  Do the pages still count as blank if they are blank but between existing stamped pages? Or do I need a certain number that are blank after the last known stamp?

I have stamps on pages 8, 11, 14 & 24 out of a total of 20 stampable pages- the rest are blank.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

A page is blank if it has nothing on it. Stamps on subsequent pages are irrelevant, a blank page is a blank page.

Some countries may have rules about needing (for example) two consecutive, facing, blank pages (so a full-page visa can go on one page and the entry/exit stamp on the one facing it), which could rule out the use of some blank pages for those countries.

I've never heard of a country requiring blank pages to be *after* all other stamps. If there is one, I'm sure their rules would make that requirement explicitly clear.

Comment: I believe you!  Thank you- with covid running rampant, it would probably take more than 7 weeks for me to renew it- and I have SO many blank pages or pages with one tiny stamp.  I see there are lines like for 4 entry/exit stamps to fit to a page- so I'll just open it to the page and gently suggest they stamp it there to start filling the gaps.  Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: on my trips in central and eastern europe, before Schengen or beyond Schengen, I saw most border officials starting to stamp on the very last page. they'd fill two of my passports from behind  which had others complain about a full passport when they leaved through it from behind, eventually finding only some blank pages near the front.

Comment: @dlatikay See also: [customs and immigration - Are there countries that are known to place their stamp at the end of the passport?] [https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/77090/are-there-countries-that-are-known-to-place-their-stamp-at-the-end-of-the-passpo]

Comment: @MarkJohnson Interesting - I would've thought that stamping at the end would be most common in countries where the primary language is read right-to-left, so anywhere they speak Arabic, Hebrew, Japanese, etc.  Doesn't seem to work out that way, oddly.

Comment: One country can't tell another country how to stamp a passport.

Comment: Blank pages are usually a sought after feature (so that visas can be put there, they cannot cover any stamps). In order to change my passport I had to have all pages non-blank (a stamp was enough). At a border (in the Middle-Esat IIRC) I specifically asked a stamp to be put on the last empty page. The border police were so surprised that they kindly asked again if I made myself clear and if I was really sure (as usually people would be asking NOT to stamp there). One of the nicest border story I had.

Comment: Irritated at how hard it was for me to maintain a document with a chronological list of my ins and outs, I opened the passport to the next page and asked the guy to use that page.  He closed it, re-opened to a random page, and stamped there.  Mexican guy opened to a full page and stamped _across_ two other stamps.

Comment: @LindseyLucas You should pass your passport to the agent open to the photo page. They will just close it and reopen to the photo page anyway. Checking you and you passport match each other, is more important to them that which pages stamps are on. They have a pretty thankless job, make it as easy as you can for them. Perhaps you could put a small post-it note, sticking out of the page you would like to be stamped, and ask them nicely **after they have identified you** to stamp that page "to help like it tidy".

Comment: @WGroleau Think about the task from the agent's perspective. They need to make sure you and the passport match. So the photo page is the one they are going to look at first. It's a busy thankless job, so they need to do their work quickly. Finding the right page for your ordering scheme is out of scope. They only need to match enter and exit stamps for their country. Yes this is annoying for you and me, but it's just life. Perhaps you could put in a small post-it note and ask them to please stamp that page, to keep things tidy, after they have identified you. Make their life as easy!

Comment: @WoJ This makes me curious *why* you would want to change your passport prematurely? Didn't like your obsolete moustache on the photo? Wanted to use modern electronic/biometric features? Wanted to hide your past travel to some country? (No need to actually answer me)

Comment: @DarcyThomas, I tried that one, too, on another entry.  Set aside the note, closed it, re-opened to a random page.

Comment: @WGroleau One of those 'Sign here' post-it note or just a piece of paper? Because they always take the bit of paper out to make it easier to scan etc. I guess the difficulty also is they may think you are trying some scam (the page you want to stamp is loose and you are gonna try remove it or something) Also there is no need to keep things in order (from their point of view). Maybe use a 'sign here' type post it with 'Please stamp here' written in the native language of the country you are visiting.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: it was 20+ years ago. In order to have visas from some countries, you had to ship your passport to the consulate (where they would keep it some time) or in some cases - to the country itself. I was travelling an awful lot at that time and it was a whole logistics to know where to change your passport so that you do not run out of space or time.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen (cont'd) Also some countries were problematic to others - I eventually ended up getting two passwords to ease the switch and separate some countries (I would not travel to countries where the fact of having visited one before is illegal - it was rather a matter to make the transition though border police easier).